Postfix emails are sent but not received
please help me, I set up postfix dovecot mysql everything is fine. Emails come to both gmail and yandex but do not come to my server, I can not understand what my mistake is, I attached the log and configuration files, please help
error in the terminal I have attached master.cf main.cf and dovecot
den@den-X99:~$ tail -n 50 /var/log/mail.log
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 37 data Date: Mon,
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 41 data Message-Id
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 31 data Content-Tr
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 23 data Content-Ty
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 0 data 
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 14 data <div>daf</
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 0 data 
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type N len 37 data --A6E1E140
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_get: type X len 0 data 
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: > mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249]:25: .
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: > mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249]:25: QUIT
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=600 enable_deadline=0
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 15 flush 3722
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 15 got 106
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: < mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249]:25: 554 5.7.1 Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1713741476-tHSX8KhbJiE0-1tly
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: connect to subsystem private/bounce
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 16 got 35
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: protocol
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute name: protocol
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute value: delivery_status_protocol
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute name: (end)
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr nrequest = 0
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr flags = 0
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr queue_id = BDEF7140836
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr original_recipient = smk.stb@yandex.ru
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr recipient = smk.stb@yandex.ru
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr offset = 242
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr dsn_orig_rcpt = rfc822;smk.stb@yandex.ru
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr notify_flags = 0
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr status = 5.7.1
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr diag_type = smtp
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr diag_text = 554 5.7.1 Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1713741476-tHSX8KhbJiE0-1tlyU6gF
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr mta_type = dns
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr mta_mname = mx.yandex.ru
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr action = failed
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: send attr reason = host mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249] said: 554 5.7.1 Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1713741476-tHSX8KhbJiE0-1tlyU6gF (in reply to end of DATA command)
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 16 flush 548
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 16 got 10
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: status
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute name: status
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute value: 0
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: input attribute name: (end)
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: BDEF7140836: to=<smk.stb@yandex.ru>, relay=mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249]:25, delay=0.78, delays=0/0.02/0.38/0.39, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.yandex.ru[77.88.21.249] said: 554 5.7.1 Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1713741476-tHSX8KhbJiE0-1tlyU6gF (in reply to end of DATA command))
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: rec_put_type: 68 at 242
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 14 flush 1
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: name_mask: resource
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/smtp[16929]: name_mask: software
Apr 22 02:17:56 den-X99 postfix/qmgr[16912]: BDEF7140836: removed

den@den-X99:~$ tail /var/log/mail.log
Apr 22 00:57:29 den-X99 postfix/smtp[12472]: rec_put_type: 68 at 242
Apr 22 00:57:29 den-X99 postfix/smtp[12472]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 14 flush 1
Apr 22 00:57:29 den-X99 postfix/smtp[12472]: name_mask: resource
Apr 22 00:57:29 den-X99 postfix/smtp[12472]: name_mask: software
Apr 22 00:57:29 den-X99 postfix/qmgr[10434]: 3219514034E: removed

main.cf

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smk-stb.ru/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smk-stb.ru/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

# Authentication
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

# Restrictions
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
     reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
     reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
     reject_unlisted_recipient,
     reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject_non_fqdn_sender,
     reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
     permit_mynetworks,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     defer_unauth_destination

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = smk-stb.ru
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = smk-stb.ru
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.105 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

debug_peer_level = 10
debug_peer_list = yandex.ru
message_size_limit = 31457280


# Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
     mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf

# Even more Restrictions and MTA params
disable_vrfy_command = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
#smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
#smtpd_hard_error_limit = 1
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
maximal_backoff_time = 3h

# Reply Rejection Codes
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550][1]```

10-mail.conf
`"
##
## Mailbox locations and namespaces
##

# Location for users' mailboxes. The default is empty, which means that Dovecot
# tries to find the mailboxes automatically. This won't work if the user
# doesn't yet have any mail, so you should explicitly tell Dovecot the full
# location.
#
# If you're using mbox, giving a path to the INBOX file (eg. /var/mail/%u)
# isn't enough. You'll also need to tell Dovecot where the other mailboxes are
# kept. This is called the "root mail directory", and it must be the first
# path given in the mail_location setting.
#
# There are a few special variables you can use, eg.:
#
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if there's no domain
#   %h - home directory
#
# See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
#   mail_location = maildir:~/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
 mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/

mail_privileged_group = mail
#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#

# If you need to set multiple mailbox locations or want to change default
# namespace settings, you can do it by defining namespace sections.
#
# You can have private, shared and public namespaces. Private namespaces
# are for user's personal mails. Shared namespaces are for accessing other
# users' mailboxes that have been shared. Public namespaces are for shared
# mailboxes that are managed by sysadmin. If you create any shared or public
# namespaces you'll typically want to enable ACL plugin also, otherwise all
# users can access all the shared mailboxes, assuming they have permissions
# on filesystem level to do so.
namespace inbox {
# Namespace type: private, shared or public
#type = private

# Hierarchy separator to use. You should use the same separator for all
# namespaces or some clients get confused. '/' is usually a good one.
# The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.
#separator = 

# Prefix required to access this namespace. This needs to be different for
# all namespaces. For example "Public/".
#prefix = 

# Physical location of the mailbox. This is in same format as
# mail_location, which is also the default for it.
#location =

# There can be only one INBOX, and this setting defines which namespace
# has it.
inbox = yes

# If namespace is hidden, it's not advertised to clients via NAMESPACE
# extension. You'll most likely also want to set list=no. This is mostly
# useful when converting from another server with different namespaces which
# you want to deprecate but still keep working. For example you can create
# hidden namespaces with prefixes "~/mail/", "~%u/mail/" and "mail/".
#hidden = no

# Show the mailboxes under this namespace with LIST command. This makes the
# namespace visible for clients that don't support NAMESPACE extension.
# "children" value lists child mailboxes, but hides the namespace prefix.
#list = yes

# Namespace handles its own subscriptions. If set to "no", the parent
# namespace handles them (empty prefix should always have this as "yes")
#subscriptions = yes

# See 15-mailboxes.conf for definitions of special mailboxes.
}

# Example shared namespace configuration
#namespace {
#type = shared
#separator = /

# Mailboxes are visible under "shared/user@domain/"
# %%n, %%d and %%u are expanded to the destination user.
#prefix = shared/%%u/

# Mail location for other users' mailboxes. Note that %variables and ~/
# expands to the logged in user's data. %%n, %%d, %%u and %%h expand to the
# destination user's data.
#location = maildir:%%h/Maildir:INDEX=~/Maildir/shared/%%u

# Use the default namespace for saving subscriptions.
#subscriptions = no

# List the shared/ namespace only if there are visible shared mailboxes.
#list = children
#}
# Should shared INBOX be visible as "shared/user" or "shared/user/INBOX"?
#mail_shared_explicit_inbox = no

# System user and group used to access mails. If you use multiple, userdb
# can override these by returning uid or gid fields. You can use either numbers
# or names. <doc/wiki/UserIds.txt>
#mail_uid =
#mail_gid =

# Group to enable temporarily for privileged operations. Currently this is
# used only with INBOX when either its initial creation or dotlocking fails.
# Typically this is set to "mail" to give access to /var/mail.

# Grant access to these supplementary groups for mail processes. Typically
# these are used to set up access to shared mailboxes. Note that it may be
# dangerous to set these if users can create symlinks (e.g. if "mail" group is
# set here, ln -s /var/mail ~/mail/var could allow a user to delete others'
# mailboxes, or ln -s /secret/shared/box ~/mail/mybox would allow reading it).
#mail_access_groups =

# Allow full filesystem access to clients. There's no access checks other than
# what the operating system does for the active UID/GID. It works with both
# maildir and mboxes, allowing you to prefix mailboxes names with eg. /path/
# or ~user/.
#mail_full_filesystem_access = no

# Dictionary for key=value mailbox attributes. This is used for example by
# URLAUTH and METADATA extensions.
#mail_attribute_dict =

# A comment or note that is associated with the server. This value is
# accessible for authenticated users through the IMAP METADATA server
# entry "/shared/comment". 
#mail_server_comment = ""

# Indicates a method for contacting the server administrator. According to
# RFC 5464, this value MUST be a URI (e.g., a mailto: or tel: URL), but that
# is currently not enforced. Use for example mailto:admin@example.com. This
# value is accessible for authenticated users through the IMAP METADATA server
# entry "/shared/admin".
#mail_server_admin = 

##
## Mail processes
##

# Don't use mmap() at all. This is required if you store indexes to shared
# filesystems (NFS or clustered filesystem).
#mmap_disable = no

# Rely on O_EXCL to work when creating dotlock files. NFS supports O_EXCL
# since version 3, so this should be safe to use nowadays by default.
#dotlock_use_excl = yes

# When to use fsync() or fdatasync() calls:
#   optimized (default): Whenever necessary to avoid losing important data
#   always: Useful with e.g. NFS when write()s are delayed
#   never: Never use it (best performance, but crashes can lose data)
#mail_fsync = optimized

# Locking method for index files. Alternatives are fcntl, flock and dotlock.
# Dotlocking uses some tricks which may create more disk I/O than other locking
# methods. NFS users: flock doesn't work, remember to change mmap_disable.
#lock_method = fcntl

# Directory where mails can be temporarily stored. Usually it's used only for
# mails larger than >= 128 kB. It's used by various parts of Dovecot, for
# example LDA/LMTP while delivering large mails or zlib plugin for keeping
# uncompressed mails.
#mail_temp_dir = /tmp

# Valid UID range for users, defaults to 500 and above. This is mostly
# to make sure that users can't log in as daemons or other system users.
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
#first_valid_uid = 500
#last_valid_uid = 0

# Valid GID range for users, defaults to non-root/wheel. Users having
# non-valid GID as primary group ID aren't allowed to log in. If user
# belongs to supplementary groups with non-valid GIDs, those groups are
# not set.
#first_valid_gid = 1
#last_valid_gid = 0

# Maximum allowed length for mail keyword name. It's only forced when trying
# to create new keywords.
#mail_max_keyword_length = 50

# ':' separated list of directories under which chrooting is allowed for mail
# processes (ie. /var/mail will allow chrooting to /var/mail/foo/bar too).
# This setting doesn't affect login_chroot, mail_chroot or auth chroot
# settings. If this setting is empty, "/./" in home dirs are ignored.
# WARNING: Never add directories here which local users can modify, that
# may lead to root exploit. Usually this should be done only if you don't
# allow shell access for users. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#valid_chroot_dirs = 

# Default chroot directory for mail processes. This can be overridden for
# specific users in user database by giving /./ in user's home directory
# (eg. /home/./user chroots into /home). Note that usually there is no real
# need to do chrooting, Dovecot doesn't allow users to access files outside
# their mail directory anyway. If your home directories are prefixed with
# the chroot directory, append "/." to mail_chroot. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#mail_chroot = 

# UNIX socket path to master authentication server to find users.
# This is used by imap (for shared users) and lda.
#auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb

# Directory where to look up mail plugins.
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules

# Space separated list of plugins to load for all services. Plugins specific to
# IMAP, LDA, etc. are added to this list in their own .conf files.
#mail_plugins = 

##
## Mailbox handling optimizations
##

# Mailbox list indexes can be used to optimize IMAP STATUS commands. They are
# also required for IMAP NOTIFY extension to be enabled.
#mailbox_list_index = yes

# Trust mailbox list index to be up-to-date. This reduces disk I/O at the cost
# of potentially returning out-of-date results after e.g. server crashes.
# The results will be automatically fixed once the folders are opened.
#mailbox_list_index_very_dirty_syncs = yes

# Should INBOX be kept up-to-date in the mailbox list index? By default it's
# not, because most of the mailbox accesses will open INBOX anyway.
#mailbox_list_index_include_inbox = no

# The minimum number of mails in a mailbox before updates are done to cache
# file. This allows optimizing Dovecot's behavior to do less disk writes at
# the cost of more disk reads.
#mail_cache_min_mail_count = 0

# When IDLE command is running, mailbox is checked once in a while to see if
# there are any new mails or other changes. This setting defines the minimum
# time to wait between those checks. Dovecot can also use inotify and
# kqueue to find out immediately when changes occur.
#mailbox_idle_check_interval = 30 secs

# Save mails with CR+LF instead of plain LF. This makes sending those mails
# take less CPU, especially with sendfile() syscall with Linux and FreeBSD.
# But it also creates a bit more disk I/O which may just make it slower.
# Also note that if other software reads the mboxes/maildirs, they may handle
# the extra CRs wrong and cause problems.
#mail_save_crlf = no

# Max number of mails to keep open and prefetch to memory. This only works with
# some mailbox formats and/or operating systems.
#mail_prefetch_count = 0

# How often to scan for stale temporary files and delete them (0 = never).
# These should exist only after Dovecot dies in the middle of saving mails.
#mail_temp_scan_interval = 1w

# How many slow mail accesses sorting can perform before it returns failure.
# With IMAP the reply is: NO [LIMIT] Requested sort would have taken too long.
# The untagged SORT reply is still returned, but it's likely not correct.
#mail_sort_max_read_count = 0

protocol !indexer-worker {
# If folder vsize calculation requires opening more than this many mails from
# disk (i.e. mail sizes aren't in cache already), return failure and finish
# the calculation via indexer process. Disabled by default. This setting must
# be 0 for indexer-worker processes.
#mail_vsize_bg_after_count = 0
}

##
## Maildir-specific settings
##

# By default LIST command returns all entries in maildir beginning with a dot.
# Enabling this option makes Dovecot return only entries which are directories.
# This is done by stat()ing each entry, so it causes more disk I/O.
# (For systems setting struct dirent->d_type, this check is free and it's
# done always regardless of this setting)
#maildir_stat_dirs = no

# When copying a message, do it with hard links whenever possible. This makes
# the performance much better, and it's unlikely to have any side effects.
#maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes

# Assume Dovecot is the only MUA accessing Maildir: Scan cur/ directory only
# when its mtime changes unexpectedly or when we can't find the mail otherwise.
#maildir_very_dirty_syncs = no

# If enabled, Dovecot doesn't use the S=<size> in the Maildir filenames for
# getting the mail's physical size, except when recalculating Maildir++ quota.
# This can be useful in systems where a lot of the Maildir filenames have a
# broken size. The performance hit for enabling this is very small.
#maildir_broken_filename_sizes = no

# Always move mails from new/ directory to cur/, even when the \Recent flags
# aren't being reset.
#maildir_empty_new = no

##
## mbox-specific settings
##

# Which locking methods to use for locking mbox. There are four available:
#  dotlock: Create <mailbox>.lock file. This is the oldest and most NFS-safe
#           solution. If you want to use /var/mail/ like directory, the users
#           will need write access to that directory.
#  dotlock_try: Same as dotlock, but if it fails because of permissions or
#               because there isn't enough disk space, just skip it.
#  fcntl  : Use this if possible. Works with NFS too if lockd is used.
#  flock  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#  lockf  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#
# You can use multiple locking methods; if you do the order they're declared
# in is important to avoid deadlocks if other MTAs/MUAs are using multiple
# locking methods as well. Some operating systems don't allow using some of
# them simultaneously.
#
# The Debian value for mbox_write_locks differs from upstream Dovecot. It is
# changed to be compliant with Debian Policy (section 11.6) for NFS safety.
#       Dovecot: mbox_write_locks = dotlock fcntl
#       Debian:  mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock
#
#mbox_read_locks = fcntl
#mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock

# Maximum time to wait for lock (all of them) before aborting.
#mbox_lock_timeout = 5 mins

# If dotlock exists but the mailbox isn't modified in any way, override the
# lock file after this much time.
#mbox_dotlock_change_timeout = 2 mins

# When mbox changes unexpectedly we have to fully read it to find out what
# changed. If the mbox is large this can take a long time. Since the change
# is usually just a newly appended mail, it'd be faster to simply read the
# new mails. If this setting is enabled, Dovecot does this but still safely
# fallbacks to re-reading the whole mbox file whenever something in mbox isn't
# how it's expected to be. The only real downside to this setting is that if
# some other MUA changes message flags, Dovecot doesn't notice it immediately.
# Note that a full sync is done with SELECT, EXAMINE, EXPUNGE and CHECK 
# commands.
#mbox_dirty_syncs = yes

# Like mbox_dirty_syncs, but don't do full syncs even with SELECT, EXAMINE,
# EXPUNGE or CHECK commands. If this is set, mbox_dirty_syncs is ignored.
#mbox_very_dirty_syncs = no

# Delay writing mbox headers until doing a full write sync (EXPUNGE and CHECK
# commands and when closing the mailbox). This is especially useful for POP3
# where clients often delete all mails. The downside is that our changes
# aren't immediately visible to other MUAs.
#mbox_lazy_writes = yes

# If mbox size is smaller than this (e.g. 100k), don't write index files.
# If an index file already exists it's still read, just not updated.
#mbox_min_index_size = 0

# Mail header selection algorithm to use for MD5 POP3 UIDLs when
# pop3_uidl_format=%m. For backwards compatibility we use apop3d inspired
# algorithm, but it fails if the first Received: header isn't unique in all
# mails. An alternative algorithm is "all" that selects all headers.
#mbox_md5 = apop3d

##
## mdbox-specific settings
##

# Maximum dbox file size until it's rotated.
#mdbox_rotate_size = 10M

# Maximum dbox file age until it's rotated. Typically in days. Day begins
# from midnight, so 1d = today, 2d = yesterday, etc. 0 = check disabled.
#mdbox_rotate_interval = 0

# When creating new mdbox files, immediately preallocate their size to
# mdbox_rotate_size. This setting currently works only in Linux with some
# filesystems (ext4, xfs).
#mdbox_preallocate_space = no

##
## Mail attachments
##

# sdbox and mdbox support saving mail attachments to external files, which
# also allows single instance storage for them. Other backends don't support
# this for now.

# Directory root where to store mail attachments. Disabled, if empty.
#mail_attachment_dir =

# Attachments smaller than this aren't saved externally. It's also possible to
# write a plugin to disable saving specific attachments externally.
#mail_attachment_min_size = 128k

# Filesystem backend to use for saving attachments:
#  posix : No SiS done by Dovecot (but this might help FS's own deduplication)
#  sis posix : SiS with immediate byte-by-byte comparison during saving
#  sis-queue posix : SiS with delayed comparison and deduplication
#mail_attachment_fs = sis posix

# Hash format to use in attachment filenames. You can add any text and
# variables: %{md4}, %{md5}, %{sha1}, %{sha256}, %{sha512}, %{size}.
# Variables can be truncated, e.g. %{sha256:80} returns only first 80 bits
#mail_attachment_hash = %{sha1}

# Settings to control adding $HasAttachment or $HasNoAttachment keywords.
# By default, all MIME parts with Content-Disposition=attachment, or inlines
# with filename parameter are consired attachments.
#   add-flags - Add the keywords when saving new mails or when fetching can
#      do it efficiently.
#   content-type=type or !type - Include/exclude content type. Excluding will
#     never consider the matched MIME part as attachment. Including will only
#     negate an exclusion (e.g. content-type=!foo/* content-type=foo/bar).
#   exclude-inlined - Exclude any Content-Disposition=inline MIME part.
#mail_attachment_detection_options =



Хорошо, Ubuntu использую

I've redone it, can you help me please

Are you running SMTP in debug mode?  If so then that's not going to help as much as the last five lines in your logs are incomplete for the entire message flow in Postfix.  Literally grab more than just base tail because that's only 5 lines.  Try tail -n 50 /var/log/mail.log and share that as an edit in your post.

please look at the result
